# Why does marijuana cause anxiety?

Tags: psychopharmacology, anxiety

Marijuana is getting increasingly used in medical settings. However, one of its disadvantages is anxiety. Does anyone know the reason behind the anxiety? Is it from the marijuana itself, or does it result secondarily due the effects of the marijuana, because, *e.g.* the user is not comfortable with the effects?

Comment: Really? Anxiety? Is that true for most people? My extremely intelligent roommate appeared much more mellow when he smoked everyday. (I rarely did it because it made my hypersomnia much worse.) The stereotype of the stoner does not suggest anxiety. Or, are you referring to medical marijuana and people using it for that reason.

Comment: What is the evidence that anxiety is a result of marijuana use?

Comment: SWIM, and some of SWIM's friends experience anxiety from marijuana, and moreso, experience anxiety as a withdrawal symptom from marijuana. there are plenty of other factors at play, but, from observation, (at the very least) marijuana seems to exacerbate anxiety in some people

Answer (score 5):

Cannabis can cause an acute and short-lasting episode of [anxiety](http://www.webmd.com/anxiety-panic/guide/mental-health-anxiety-disorders), which often resembles a state of [panic](http://www.webmd.com/anxiety-panic/guide/mental-health-panic-disorder). When taken in high doses these effects can be intense and turn into attacks of panic and [phobia](http://www.webmd.com/anxiety-panic/tc/phobias-topic-overview). About 20–30% of users show brief acute anxiety reactions after smoking the drug. These symptoms tend to occur more in drug-naive subjects and in novel or stressful environments. In contrast, long-term users typically report that cannabis reduces their anxiety [(Crippa *et al*, 2009)](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Zerrin_Atakan/publication/26754337_Cannabis_and_anxiety_a_critical_review_of_the_evidence/links/09e415075bc44046dd000000.pdf).

Anxiety is also one of the main manifestations of the [cannabis withdrawal syndrome](http://www.webmd.com/mental-health/addiction/news/20080507/withdrawal-symptoms-from-smoking-pot). Its onset is typically between the second and sixth day and lasts from 4 to 14 days.

The main active psychoactive ingredient in cannabis, [delta-9-tetrahydrocannabinol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahydrocannabinol) (THC), affects serotonergic, noradrenergic, GABAergic and glutamatergic transmission, but there is relatively little known about how it exactly induces anxiety. One of the reasons being that the [psychotic effects of cannabis consumption](https://www.sane.org/mental-health-and-illness/facts-and-guides/cannabis-and-psychotic-illness) has received way more attention, likely because it is a more severe side effect than the anxiety symptoms. [Cannabidiol](https://www.drugabuse.gov/about-nida/legislative-activities/testimony-to-congress/2016/biology-potential-therapeutic-effects-cannabidiol) has been associated with an [anxiolytic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anxiolytic) effect, perhaps through its effects on [5HT<sub>1A</sub>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/5-HT1A_receptor) receptors [(Crippa *et al*, 2009)](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Zerrin_Atakan/publication/26754337_Cannabis_and_anxiety_a_critical_review_of_the_evidence/links/09e415075bc44046dd000000.pdf).

It has been shown that the amount of anxiety also depends on the genetic make-up of the user [(Otten *et al*., 2016)](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/adb.12372/pdf).

Acute intoxication could also lead to anxiety secondary to impaired cognitive functioning and the clouding of consciousness [(Crippa *et al*, 2009)](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Zerrin_Atakan/publication/26754337_Cannabis_and_anxiety_a_critical_review_of_the_evidence/links/09e415075bc44046dd000000.pdf), as mentioned in the question by the OP.

<sub>**References**

**-** [Crippa *et al*., *Hum Psychopharmacol Clin Exp* (2009); **24**: 515–23](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Zerrin_Atakan/publication/26754337_Cannabis_and_anxiety_a_critical_review_of_the_evidence/links/09e415075bc44046dd000000.pdf)

**-** [Otten *et al*., *Addict Biol* (2016); [Epub ahead of print]](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/adb.12372/pdf)</sub>

Comment: Nice answer! +1 but couldn't you also mention that anandamide which is an endocannabinoid, changes the consciousness of the consumer, because the endocannabinoids function as neuromodulators, which can suppress the release of the neurotransmitter GABA in the hippocampus, and therefore might be responsible for changes in the perception?

Comment: @JordiZambrino - Thanks!! As for your suggestion- the question is on anxiety, so I have not included it's other effects here.